# Junit verify command execution

Tags: java, junit

I have testcase:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testRunWithLessThanTwoParameters_IllegalArgumentException() 
    throws Exception {

    final String[] args = { "Less Number of parameters" };
    command = spy(new GenerateSummaryReportCommand());      
    commandLine = new PosixParser().parse(new Options(),Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length));
    assertEquals(0, command.run(commandLine));      
    verify(command, times(1)).usage();
}
```

I would like to know whether verify will be executed after assertEqual statement

Comment: quick answer, if assertEquals fails, No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `parse` is throwing the `IllegalArgumentException`. If that is the case, neither `assertEquals` nor `verify` will get executed because the exception was throw above them. The way to do verification after an exception is thrown is to put the verification in a `catch` block.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testRunWithLessThanTwoParameters_IllegalArgumentException() 
   throws Exception {

     final String[] args = { "Less Number of parameters" };
     command = spy(new GenerateSummaryReportCommand());      

   try{
     commandLine = new PosixParser().parse(new Options(),Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length));
   }catch (Exception e){
     assertEquals(0, command.run(commandLine));      
     verify(command, times(1)).usage();

      throw e;
   }
 }
```

Notice that I rethrow the exception to allow for the `expected` check.